# Trying to understand how to constrain generics by type parameters and `keyof` in Typescript 2.x

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

*Using Typescript v2.4.1 with default (empty) `compilerOptions`.*

I understand normally generics can be used to constrain the return type of a function or class method to be the same type as a passed paramter. However, I understood `keyof` gives a little more power and I'm trying to use it to constrain the return type of a class method to be the same as a stored property value.

The very last line (assignment to x) is is giving me the following compile error (somehow related to type widening it seems):

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> > Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
// vim: set et sw=4 ts=4 ff=unix ft=javascript :

class Store<S, K extends keyof S> {
    private store: S;
    constructor(storeDefaults: S) {
        this.store = storeDefaults;
    }
    get(key: K): S[K] {
        return this.store[key];
    }
}

const store = new Store({
    x: 'hello',
    y: 7,
});

const x: string = store.get('x'); // should succeed, but shows an error
//const y: string = store.get('y'); // should fail as y is a number
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this (if it is achievable), or if not, how `keyof` should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the parameter type is resolved in `Store` construction time, which is a bit "too soon" for the `get` method to work properly for any type of key. The created store resolves `K` specifically to the widest type possible `K = keyof S = "x" | "y"`, in which the possible values of the store's state is `"string" | "number"`. The information about the mapping from a key type to a value type was lost in the process.

If you move the generic type `K` to the method, the compiler will evaluate it on each particular call, thus clearing the ambiguity.

```
class Store<S> {
    private store: S;
    constructor(storeDefaults: S) {
        this.store = storeDefaults;
    }
    get<K extends keyof S>(key: K): S[K] {
        return this.store[key];
    }
}

const store = new Store({
    x: 'hello',
    y: 7,
});

const x: string = store.get('x'); // ok!
```